# Problems with Debian Wheezy installation

Tags: debian, gnome, gnome3

I recently installed Debian Wheezy 7.6 in my laptop which has 4GB nVidia graphics card. By default, on login it boots into gnome classic mode and reports **"gnome 3 failed to load"**. Also, sometimes the mouse pointer is not consistent (goes invisible while scrolling and clicking).

This is the output of `.xsession-errors`:

```
/etc/gdm3/Xsession: Beginning session setup...
localuser:a12 being added to access control list
openConnection: connect: No such file or directory
cannot connect to brltty at :0
gnome-keyring-daemon: insufficient process capabilities, unsecure memory might get used
gnome-keyring-daemon: insufficient process capabilities, unsecure memory might get used
gnome-keyring-daemon: insufficient process capabilities, unsecure memory might get used
gnome-keyring-daemon: insufficient process capabilities, unsecure memory might get used
GNOME_KEYRING_CONTROL=/home/a12/.cache/keyring-VJMq1w
GNOME_KEYRING_CONTROL=/home/a12/.cache/keyring-VJMq1w
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/home/a12/.cache/keyring-VJMq1w/ssh
GNOME_KEYRING_CONTROL=/home/a12/.cache/keyring-VJMq1w
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/home/a12/.cache/keyring-VJMq1w/ssh
GPG_AGENT_INFO=/home/a12/.cache/keyring-VJMq1w/gpg:0:1
GNOME_KEYRING_CONTROL=/home/a12/.cache/keyring-VJMq1w
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/home/a12/.cache/keyring-VJMq1w/ssh

(gnome-settings-daemon:16895): color-plugin-WARNING **: failed to get edid: unable to get EDID for output

(gnome-settings-daemon:16895): color-plugin-WARNING **: unable to get EDID for xrandr-default: unable to get EDID for output

(gnome-settings-daemon:16895): color-plugin-WARNING **: failed to reset xrandr-default gamma tables: gamma size is zero

(gnome-panel:16921): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_accelerator_parse_with_keycode: assertion `accelerator != NULL' failed

** (gnome-panel:16921): WARNING **: Unable to parse mouse modifier '(null)'

Initializing tracker-store...
vmware-user: could not open /proc/fs/vmblock/dev
Tracker-Message: Setting up monitor for changes to config file:'/home/a12/.config/tracker/tracker-store.cfg'
Tracker-Message: Setting up monitor for changes to config file:'/home/a12/.config/tracker/tracker-store.cfg'
Starting log:
  File:'/home/a12/.local/share/tracker/tracker-store.log'
Initializing tracker-miner-fs...
Tracker-Message: Setting up monitor for changes to config file:'/home/a12/.config/tracker/tracker-miner-fs.cfg'
Starting log:
  File:'/home/a12/.local/share/tracker/tracker-miner-fs.log'

** (gnome-screensaver:16959): WARNING **: Config key not handled: disable-application-handlers

** (gnome-screensaver:16959): WARNING **: Config key not handled: disable-command-line

** (gnome-screensaver:16959): WARNING **: Config key not handled: disable-log-out

** (gnome-screensaver:16959): WARNING **: Config key not handled: disable-print-setup

** (gnome-screensaver:16959): WARNING **: Config key not handled: disable-printing

** (gnome-screensaver:16959): WARNING **: Config key not handled: disable-save-to-disk

(gnome-panel:16921): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_accelerator_parse_with_keycode: assertion `accelerator != NULL' failed

** (gnome-panel:16921): WARNING **: Unable to parse mouse modifier '(null)'

** Message: applet now removed from the notification area

(gnome-panel:16921): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: /tmp/buildd/glib2.0-2.33.12+really2.32.4/./gobject/gsignal.c:2459: signal `size_request' is invalid for instance `0x230b6c0'
** Message: applet now embedded in the notification area
Initializing nautilus-gdu extension

(gnome-settings-daemon:16895): updates-plugin-WARNING **: Failed to get symlink: Error when getting information for file '/run/udev/firmware-missing/ar3k/ramps_0x31010000_40.dfu': No such file or directory
Shutting down nautilus-gdu extension
Window manager warning: Log level 16: Error converting selection
Window manager warning: Log level 16: Error converting selection
Window manager warning: Log level 16: Error converting selection
Window manager warning: Log level 16: Error converting selection
Window manager warning: Log level 16: Error converting selection
Window manager warning: Log level 16: Error converting selection
Window manager warning: Log level 16: Error converting selection
Window manager warning: Log level 16: Error converting selection

(gnome-settings-daemon:16895): PackageKit-WARNING **: couldn't parse execption 'GDBus.Error:org.gtk.GDBus.UnmappedGError.Quark._pk_5ftransaction_5ferror.Code4: GetDistroUpgrades not supported by backend', please report

(gnome-settings-daemon:16895): updates-plugin-WARNING **: failed to get upgrades: GDBus.Error:org.gtk.GDBus.UnmappedGError.Quark._pk_5ftransaction_5ferror.Code4: GetDistroUpgrades not supported by backend
```

I've no idea what these are. I googled and cannot find a solution to it. Was it due to my graphics card? If so how can I resolve them?

**UPDATE: I really don't want gnome-3 but the classic mode. So, it is suffice for the classic mode to be perfect.**

Comment: I might be able to help. Do you have any other environments installed? Or will any of the others work?

Comment: @AmateurProgramer No, it is a clean install from debian gnome live cd.

Comment: Do you have any sort of access to a command line?

Comment: Yes I had. But now I restarted and it keeps saying that `xchi-queue-intr-tx:70 callbacks suppressed `

Comment: I think we should install 'Xfce' and uninstall 'Gnome' for now. Get 'Xfce' to work, and through that, we will install Gnome.

Comment: I tried to start gnome by using the command `startx` but it says xauth some file not found

Comment: Was that the problem due to live CD?

Comment: More than likely yes... There is some corrupted files.

Comment: OK I'm uninstalling gnome and try to install xfce and will tell you the result

Answer (score 1):

Upgrading the kernel did solved the issues with mouse pointers, which is available using the wheezy [backports](https://wiki.debian.org/Backports). Add the backports repo to your `/etc/apt/sources.list` and give the following commands:

```
#login as root
su
#update packages
apt-get update
#install through backports
apt-get -t wheezy-backports install linux-image-3.16-0.bpo.3-amd64  firmware-linux-free
```

But, gnome 3 didn't worked which I don't care. Gnome fallback works perfect now except some ugly icon rendering in the panel.